# Configuring a TcpInboundGateway to send multiple responses to the same message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tcp, spring-integration

I currently have a `TcpInboundGateway` that takes in messages, does some processing on the message and then returns the appropriate response, all as a `TcpInboundGateway` should.

However, I am curious if this `TcpInboundGateway` can be configured in such a way that it will send an immediate response to the originating request but continue to process the request and send the post-processing response as well?

Think of this immediate response as an acknowledgement to the sender that the message was received.

**Possible Solution:**

After reviewing this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568806/spring-integration-tcp-inbound-outbound-adapter-with-non-spring-client), I came up with what I believe to be a viable solution to this problem.

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class Configuration {

    @Bean
    public AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverConnectionFactory() {
        return new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(2002);
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter inboundAdapter(AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverConnectionFactory) {
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter inboundAdapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        inboundAdapter.setConnectionFactory(serverConnectionFactory);
        inboundAdapter.setOutputChannelName("sendAcknowledgement");
        return inboundAdapter;
    }

    @MessageEndpoint
    public class InboundMessageHandler {

        @Autowired
        private OutboundMessageGateway gateway;

        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="sendAcknowledgement", outputChannel="doProcessing")
        public Message<String> initialAck(Message<String> message) {
            gateway.send("ACK", message.getHeaders().get(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID).toString());
            return message;
        }

        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="doProcessing", outputChannel="sendResponse")
        public Message<String> mockDelay(Message<String> message) throws InterruptedException {
            return message;
        }
    }

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel="sendResponse")
    public interface OutboundMessageGateway {
        void send(@Payload String message, @Header(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID) String connectionId);
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="sendResponse")
    public TcpSendingMessageHandler outboundAdapter(AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverConnectionFactory) {
        TcpSendingMessageHandler outboundAdapter = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        outboundAdapter.setConnectionFactory(serverConnectionFactory);
        return outboundAdapter;
    }

}
```

Comment: Looking at [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.M4/reference/html/ip.html#ip-collaborating-adapters) it sounds like collaborating channel adapters might be the route to go for this... In search of any examples that are available.

Answer (score 0):

For the use-case with the `TcpInboundGateway` and acking with later reply you need to use a `PublishSubscribeChannel` with an `Executor` injected to make a processing async.

The first subscriber should return some ack into the `replyChannel` header. This way your `TcpInboundGateway` will perform request-reply and return that ack into the socket connected.

At the same time as you want, the second subscriber can perform desired logic and build the real reply later. Only the point that we need to use the mention in the docs [Collaborating Outbound and Inbound Channel Adapters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#ip-collaborating-adapters) (as you noticed already). So, since `TcpInboundGateway` populates an `IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID` header into a request message, it is going to be available in your async process and subsequent `TcpSendingMessageHandler` will know where to send your processed reply:

```
private void handleMessageAsServer(Message<?> message) {
    // We don't own the connection, we are asynchronously replying
    String connectionId = message.getHeaders().get(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID, String.class);
    TcpConnection connection = null;
    if (connectionId != null) {
        connection = this.connections.get(connectionId);
    }
    if (connection != null) {
        try {
            connection.send(message);
        }
```

So, what you need is like this:

1. a `PublishSubscribeChannel` with an `executor` for your `TcpInboundGateway`
2. A simple handler to reply with an ack as a first subscriber
3. A sub-flow for processing a request
4. A `TcpSendingMessageHandler` to send a process response into the same TCP connection.

Comment: Artem is there any benefit to this solution than an implementation that uses just the Inbound and Outbound adapters? I believe I have gotten close on a solution of that manner but if this is the better approach I have a few questions... See next comment.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by inject an executor into the PublishSubscribeChannel? Do you have an example of using the TcpSendingMessageHandler to sending the subsequent request?

Comment: Well, thinking about this one more time, I would say that is is really better to use just channel Adapters pair and send both ack and response message to the outbound channel Adapter. That way you won’t bother yourself with the publish subscribe

Comment: Artem, thanks for the quick response. I have edited my original question to include a possible solution. Curious your thoughts on the implementation and if this solution can be reused to support multiple connections on different ports?